# Apple Script is undeleting files (Lion) and the OS keeps asking for a password. Is there a way around this.

Tags: osx-lion, applescript

So a funny thing happened to me last night. I was trying to clean files off my Macbook Pro.

I just purchased a new Macbook Retina and it has a smaller hard drive than my old Macbook Pro (I know cry me a river).

Anyway I was in Finder and I found a whole bunch of files and I selected them all and hit the good old delete key.

And gosh darn if my Mac didn’t immediately got to working whacking my files. What I didn’t realize that I had a view of my entire network of files including my Dropbox documents, family pictures and even some naughty images from my college years (don’t tell my wonderful wife).

The total number of deleted files was over 4,000. I almost cried.

No big deal I just go to the Trash and undelete right? Not so fast Tonto!

I want to have the files moved back to their original location. While the Lion supports this feature, it will only allow you do restore one file at a time.

With 4,000+ files my eyeballs would fall out by the time I finished.

Fortunately someone at Apple invented Apple Script.

And someone else wrote a script that will undelete files one file at a time.

I ran the script went to bed and found that it worked!!!!

Of the 4,000 file only 1,700 remained in my trash (Woo Hoo!!!).

The problem is the remaining files require me to enter a password before the restore can take place. I believe these files were created under a different owner.

My question is how can I get around this?

Is there a way to enter a super duper user mode that eliminates me having to enter a password for every file I want to undelete?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the Apple Scrpt:

```
  repeat 4173 times --or as many files you have

          tell application "Finder" to open trash --open the trash folder

          tell application "Finder" to activate

          tell application "System Events"

                    tell process "Finder"

  delay 0.2 -- adjust delay as needed

  key code 125 --move down to get focus on a file

  key down command --hold command key

  delay 0.2 -- adjust delay as needed

  key code 51 --hit delete

  key up command --release command

                    end tell

          end tell

  delay 0.2 -- adjust delay as needed

          tell application "Finder" to close every window --close everything for the next cycle

end repeat
```

Comment: The question was cross-posted at [Super User](http://superuser.com/a/451541/69039); my answer contains an alternative script that just automates typing the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine you don't want to answer my question! I'll answer it myself (>:P).

Anyway my issue was caused by file permissions. Some files were locked down in such a way that I needed to enter a password to undelete them.

I was able to fix this using the chmod command.

Cheers!!!!